# Overriding Tomca7 Maven Plugin configuration

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

I am working in a project that uses a tomcat7-maven-plugin for testing, defined in the pom like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>9092</port>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Is there a way to start this on a different port without editing the pom? When running `mvn tomcat7:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=9099` it still starts the tomcat on port 9092. I can't change the pom permanently due to others in the project desiring this default configuration, and I don't want to have to edit it locally every time I start the tomcat.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Add a property in your POM, with the value you want as the default. Reference that property in your configuration. Then simply pass the Maven property on the command line in the standard way to override.

Comment: That solved it, thanks!